# Selenium is unable to initiate a chrome/firefox session when used by Jenkins in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying for 2 days to get a jenkins setup up and running on ubuntu 14.04. Also I used Ubuntu/Linux for the first time 3 days ago, so I still have plenty to learn.

**The environment**:

- Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64 on a VM (Host-OS is Windows 7 x64)
- selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
- Jenkins .deb package v1.619
- Apache Maven 3.2.3
- JDK 1.8.0 (Java 8)
- Jetty 9.14 distribution

It works fine on Windows 7. It also works perfect when I'm running each component from the terminal as **'root'** (4 separate terminals):

Hub:`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub -hubConfig hubConfig.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver`

Node:`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver`

Jetty:`java -jar start.jar`

Node.js (Asynchronously) + Selenium test suite: `mvn install`

In the Jenkins client (localhost:8082/), I have a job called 'Selenium'. Inside of this job i'm building 3 maven pom.xml files. The first pom.xml file prepares the resources needed for Jetty to run and runs it, the second pom.xml files prepares Selenium (download + setup nodeConfig and hubConfig + start hub/node) and the third one executes a 'node app.js' command, compiles the classes for Selenium and executes the tests; the problem is that the tests are not executed and the following errors appear (chrome/firefox is not launching at all, the rest of the project builds without a problem):

- The error for firefox (Has the webdriver built-in) when running the build from Jenkins:

*Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37' System info: host: 'jason-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver Command duration or timeout: 46.53 seconds Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55' System info: host: 'jason-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver*

- The error for chrome when running the build from Jenkins:

*unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 60.70 seconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37' System info: host: 'jason-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Command duration or timeout: 61.52 seconds Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bceef1bc36d43f3dc0b83c88998168a363a0', time: '2014-09-10 09:43:55' System info: host: 'jason-VirtualBox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver*

What I've tried to do to solve this issue:

- I've changed the ownership of the 'Selenium' job folder to 'root' (first try, thought this would work) and 'jason' (second try; jason is the main user).
- chown -R jenkins:root /relevant/jenkins/directories/
- chmod 777 -R /on/everything (This crashed the whole system)

Relevant pom.xml parts:
http://pastebin.com/gKee7vE6

So... as far as I understood through my short travel in the realm of linux... there are some permission issues here, am I right (Jenkins <-> Browsers?)? Anybody else experienced this problem before? Any suggestions on how to solve it? Should I try with Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by disabling Jenkins, so that it doesn't run on startup anymore (As user 'jenkins'). 
Jenkins is executed at startup with:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8081 --ajp13Port=-1
```

I'm starting it manually using a script that executes on startup the .war file:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```

My guess is that either the OS didn't allow the user 'jenkins' to open a firefox/chrome session, either one of the parameters used by the user 'jenkins' to start the jenkins process was blocking it from using chrome/firefox.